# Is it possible to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\frac{d^ng}{dx^n}$, for infinitely-differentiable $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, fourier-transform

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be infinitely differentiable. Is it possible to simplify the following infinite sum?

$$S=fg+\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}\frac{d^3g}{dx^3}+\cdots \;=\;\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\frac{d^ng}{dx^n} \tag{1}$$

The expression above bears some resemblance with the following sum:

$S_{f}=f+\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}+... \tag{2}=f(x+1)$

I feel it may be possible to compute $(1)$ using the Fourier transform. Although it is quite evident that $S_f$ can be obtained from the Taylor series, using the Fourier transform

$\mathcal{F}\{S_f\}=\mathcal{F}\{f\}+\mathcal{F}\{df/dx\}+\frac{1}{2!}\mathcal{F}\{d^2f/dx^2\}+...=(1+i\omega+\frac{1}{2!}(i\omega)^2+...)\mathcal{F}\{f\}=e^{i\omega}\mathcal{F}\{f\}\tag{3}$

therefore, $S_f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{e^{i\omega}\mathcal{F}\{f\}\}=f(x+1)$.

If I use the same approach for $S$, assuming that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively, using the convolution theorem, I get:

$S=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}*\mathcal{G}+i\omega\mathcal{F}*i\omega \mathcal{G}+\frac{1}{2!}(i\omega)^2\mathcal{F}*(i\omega)^2 \mathcal{G}+...\} \tag{4}$

where $*$ is the convolution operator. Any hint how can I proceed further?

Comment: There are a few things that are off in your formulas: 1/ don't you intend the first term of $S$ to be $fg$ ? 2/ In the final formula, where does the $\mathcal{F}*\mathcal{G}$ term come from? And if you correct with my suggestion in point 1, where does the term $\mathcal{F}$ come from?

Comment: Finally, if you work out $\mathcal{F}*\mathcal{G}+i\omega\mathcal{F}*i\omega \mathcal{G}+\frac{1}{2!}(i\omega)^2\mathcal{F}*(i\omega)^2 \mathcal{G}+...$, you can represent it as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp[\tau(\omega-\tau)]\mathcal{F}(\tau)\mathcal{G}(\omega-\tau)d\tau$. Don't know what you can do with it after that.

Comment: Assuming $f,g$ entire:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac 1{n!}f^{(n)}(x)g^{(n)}(x)&=\mathrm{res}_{z=0}\sum_{n,m\geq 0}\frac 1{m!}f^{(m)}z^m(x)g^{(n)}(x)z^{-1-n}\mathrm d z
\\
&=\mathrm{res}_{z=0}f(x+z)G(z,x)\mathrm d z
\end{align}
where
$$
G(z,x):=\int_0^{+\infty}g(x+h)\exp(-h z)\mathrm d h.
$$
I do not think anything much nicer can be said in general.

Comment: @Raskolnikov thanks for the commen. I have modified the formulas.

Comment: @Raskolnikov shouldn't $e^{\tau (\omega - \tau)}$ be $e^{-\tau (\omega - \tau)}$ instead?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I dropped the minus by accident when copying from my notes.